# Java: Regex for Parsing Positive and Negative Doubles

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse doubles from a line of text. I found few lines of code that I thought was doing what I wanted. However, I discovered it would not parse negative doubles (would just parse them as positive). I am totally new to regex and its a little overwhelming. I was wonder if someone could explain the code below and tell me what each part means, and how I would modify it so it will parse both positive and negative doubles? Thanks in advance!

```
double nextDouble;
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)").matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) nextDouble = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1)));
```

EDIT: Here is an example of a line. 
"104.44518717, 34.09785265, 103.39288764, 0.09813121, 0.00000000, -0.46612322, 4.68576504"

It parses -0.46612322 as 0.46612322.

Comment: Any particular reason against using [Double.parseDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: And Scanner.nextDouble()?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka - Look at the code.  After getting the potential double from inside a string, it *is* using `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: I see, sorry. Got ahead of myself ^^

Comment: If all the lines you need to process is like the sample line (comma separated numbers). Assuming that the numbers aren't formatted to separate every 3 digits with a comma (Eg 1,234,567.99999). You can simply use line.split(",") and Double.parse() to get the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you have has two parts.

The fist part in the brackets is ensuring that the matching string isn't preceded by digits 
and points. Not sure why you need that part, if you provide a sample line that would help.

The second part in the brakets is the matching part. That just says match 1 or more digits and points.

If you want to make your expression to work with negative numbers you can just add the '-' character to the matching set.

```
(?!=\\d-\\.)([-\\d\\.]+)
```

But this, as well as your expression will match strings with multiple points(dots). Eg 122.12.12

So I suggest you try the following. Note that i removed the first part.

```
(-?(\\d)+(\\.)?(\\d)*)
```

Comment: Better: `-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?` and use `group(0)`, not `group(1)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopoliik Yes, i think that's the way if you don't want to match something like "123."

Answer (score 1):

Try with following regex:

```
(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)
```

Comment: That did not work. I have edited my post with an example line.

Comment: This doesn't accept integer representation, which is legal for a double.

Comment: Silly me, I put it in the wrong spot (I had another regex in my code too). Works perfectly. Do you mind explaining what each part means?

Comment: `-?` - optional minus sign; `\\d+` - one on more digits; `\\.` dot sign because `.` is treated as any character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))(([Ee][+-]?)?\\d+)?"
```