# How to pull double out of string with matcher

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse a double out of a string. I have the code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("reciproc(2.00000000000)");
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(m.group()));
```

This code throws a java.lang.IllegalStateException. I want the output to be 2.00000000000. I got the regex from [Java: Regex for Parsing Positive and Negative Doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380153/java-regex-for-parsing-positive-and-negative-doubles) where it seemed to work for them. I tried a few other regexs as well and they all threw the same error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: So whats your result?

Comment: it throws a java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: Check the string passed to `Pattern.matcher()`. Do you think it will match with the regex you have given?

Comment: Pattern.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", "reciproc(2.00000000000)") returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with your regex but in how you are using the Matcher class. You need to call find() first.

This should work:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    String text = "reciproc(2.00000000000)";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(text.substring(m.start(), m.end())));
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("reciproc(2.00000000000)");
    if(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(m.group()));
    }
```

For more information, see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

`p.matcher("2.000000000000");`

Your pattern should match the regex provided in `Pattern.compile()`

For more information on regex and patterns:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: whats your answer exactly? I need to pull it out of "reciproc(2.00000000000)"